# Using Symfony Project with Newer Installation

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have been handed an old project from a later version of Symfony, and am attempting to use it with Symfony 1.4 on Linux. I am unsure which version of Symfony it was originally created with.

I installed the copy of Symfony 1.4.11 into the project, as described in the tutorial, [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.symfony-project.org%2Fget%2Fpdf%2Fjobeet-1.4-propel-en.pdf). The project is now throwing the following error:

```
500 | Internal Server Error | sfParseException
Configuration file "/path/to/project/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/config/config/filters.yml" specifies category "common" with missing class key.
```

The closest I found was a [trac ticket](http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/7156) which suggested I upgrade the project. I ran the `symfony project:validate` command, which turned up `input_in_place_editor_tag`, an apparently deprecated method, in one of the templates. I can't find any information on this method for 1.4, or what I should use in its place.

Are there any known fixes to this problem? Is it possible to use a project created with a previous version of Symfony with a later one?

Comment: I would setup the old project clean first and run "symfony -V" in the project root to find out what version it was created in. The old project should contain everything it needs to run, regardless of its version. There are differences between the various 1.x versions. If it's old, it's unlikely to be as simple as just copying some files over to the new project.

Comment: The project doesn't have its own copy of Symfony, and appears to have relied on an installation external to it. Running `symfony -V` throws an error, saying it can't find sfCoreAutoload.class.php.

Comment: @Druckles... Sounds like you're in for some headache. I've only worked with 1.4 so perhaps someone familiar with older versions can help. There's a few people like that hanging about the Symfony forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who might come across a similar problem, try deleting the line `common: ~` from /path/to/project/apps/application/config/filters.yml. This solved the problem for me.

This thread also helped: http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/62891/

Any further problems might be caused by `on` and `off` in your .yml configuration files. Symfony 1.4 appears to use `true` and `false` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how old the project is, it's quite possible it's been created with an old version, and will not work with the most recent one. 1.4 broke backwards compatibility by removing many deprecated stuff, mostly from the 1.0 era.

If I'd were you I'd try it first with 1.0, then work my way up to 1.3 (which is 1.4 including the deprecated stuff). Also don't forget to check config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php for the require at the beginning to see where it tries to load symfony from.

If you just need to maintain the project, I wouldn't bother upgrading it from an old version to 1.4. Even if it needs upgrading, it can wait till Symfony2 is here - which is probably another month or so.